# Small issue with PHP Form

Tags: php, email

I try a small PHP script to submit a email to my email from a page.
All works but somehow it does not specifie the "From" address. In them email I get it shows Apache and has the server email in.

I would be happy if anyone would be able to give me a pointer on where I messed up.
Here is the script

```
<?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "info@domain.com";

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "index.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "thank_you.html";

/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
$email_subject = "Newsletter Signup";
$headers = 'From: BSM Admin <info@domain.com>';

$msg = 
"Subject: " . $email_subject . "\r\n" . 
"You have received a newsletter subscription for Domain" . "\r\n" . 
"Email: " . $email_address ;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($email_address)) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

/* 
If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
If you add a form field, you should add it here.
*/
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {

    mail( "$webmaster_email", "$email_subject", $headers, $msg );
    header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

When I get the email it specifies a server default email instead of the $headers variable.

From    apache@server_address.net (Apache)

Thank you for the help, I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Are you getting the correct message on the email? Checking the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) for **mail** it seems the third paramenter should be the message and the headers should be the fourth, you have them backward on your code.

Comment: I changed it to 

 mail( $headers, $webmaster_email, $email_subject, $msg );
 header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );

but still the same. I do get the $headers but in tghe message body

Comment: `$email_address = $_POST['email_address'] ;` might be what you need

Comment: Try mail( $webmaster_email,  $email_subject, $msg,  $headers);

Comment: Juan V, you are correct. It was simply the order if the fields. I tried all kind of things but i did not assume it was that simple. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
else {
    $from = 'your.from@emailaddress.com';
    mail( $webmaster_email , "Feedback Form Results", $msg, "From: {$from}\r\nReturn-Path: {$from}");

    header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
```

Comment: If you wish to gain more reputation please do your best and put more effort in properly formatting your answers. +1 for encouragement. You should also describe what was wrong as well. Code only answers are considered low quality.